# How to read a log textfile live that is constantly updating in server to web textbox without reloading the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

the log file will be in notepad format the values will be like this *11.23445646,56.3456578954* 10.23445646,26.3456578954 16.23445646,-46.3456578954 I'm planning to get the data from server to website textbox, of first value which I marked as italic the values will change after few seconds the updated value will come first.

I tried some PHP example but not getting it in the below text box the values I need to get..if i get also every time i need to reload the page to get updated value. for example: x=11.23445646, y=56.3456578954,

```
Longtitude <input id="x" type="number" value = "" onkeyup="updateMarker('x')">

Latitude <input id="y" type="number"value = "" onkeyup="updateMarker('y')">
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/auto-refresh-div-content-jquery-ajax/

the above example show how to implement, is it possible to reload or update the values alone without reloading the whole page. in few examples they mentioned ajax i tried but not getting output.  i know only few in php,javascript.i'm new to ajax. Pls  guide me

Comment: Do you need to know immediately when the server has new data or do you want to simply *request* for data?

Comment: @Norman Breau  immediately  whenever i get an update in server file i need a update in my browser, if this is not possible means  request for data at set of interval of seconds...the main part is whole webpage should not reload.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you in a reasonable time. The most efficient way to do this is WebSockets, as it allows a connection be be persistant and open, so the server can send any updates immediately when availables are available. However if your target browsers don't support WebSockets, then you should fallback to long-poll requests.

Answer (score 0):

For updating your page without refreshing it I would suggest using WebSockets in combination with jQuery or whatever you would like to use. Be sure to check if your target browsers [support WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).

If you want to use NodeJs on your server you could use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) and start looking into the Chat Example to get a clue how it works. The good thing about Socket.io is that it provides fallback for older browsers and switches to polling if WebSockets aren't supported.